# Problems with results

Tags: java, conditional-statements, eclipse-jee

hello ? please this is my Code in Java , It  works but the categorie of the word do not appear in the console :

So , I am follwing the exercices  so that the methode categorie shoulb be private but i am wondering if i have failed somewhere

```
package packageSdz1;



// portée de la classe : public 
/* private :  méthode utilisée 
*que dans la classe où elle est mentionnée
public class Ville {
*/

public class Ville {


    // public sans ajout de portée

       //Les variables de classe : celles-ci sont communes à 
        //toutes les instances de votre classe.

    private String nomVille;
    private String nomPays;
    private int nbreHabitants;
    private char categorie;



    //Variables publiques qui comptent les instances
    public static int nbreInstances = 0;

      //Variable privée qui comptera aussi les instances
    private static int nbreInstancesBis = 0;   




    //Constructeur par défaut , es variables d'instance : ce sont elles 
    // qui définiront les caractéristiques de notre objet.
      public Ville(){

        System.out.println("Création d'une ville !");      
        nomVille = "Inconnu";
        nomPays = "Inconnu";
        nbreHabitants = 0;


        //On incrémente nos variables à chaque appel aux constructeurs
        nbreInstances++;
        nbreInstancesBis++;          
        //Le reste ne change pas.
      } 


          //Constructeur avec paramètres
          //J'ai ajouté un « p » en première lettre des paramètres.
          //Ce n'est pas une convention, mais ça peut être un bon moyen de les repérer.
          public Ville(String pNom, int pNbre, String pPays)
          {

            System.out.println("Création d'une ville avec des paramètres !");
            nomVille = pNom;
            nomPays = pPays;
            nbreHabitants = pNbre;



            nbreInstances++;
            nbreInstancesBis++;  
          }        




        //*************   ACCESSEURS *************


          public static int getNombreInstancesBis()
          {
            return nbreInstancesBis;
          }  
          //Le reste du code est le même qu'avant




          //Retourne le nom de la ville
          public String getNom()  {  
            return nomVille;
          }

          //Retourne le nom du pays
          public String getNomPays()
          {
            return nomPays;
          }

          // Retourne le nombre d'habitants
          public int getNombreHabitants()
          {
            return nbreHabitants;
          } 
          //Retourne la catégorie de la ville
              public char getCategorie()
              {
                return categorie;
              } 

          //*************   MUTATEURS   *************

          //Définit le nom de la ville
          public void setNom(String pNom)
          {
            nomVille = pNom;
          }

          //Définit le nom du pays
          public void setNomPays(String pPays)
          {
            nomPays = pPays;
          }

          //Définit le nombre d'habitants
          public void setNombreHabitants(int nbre)
          {
            nbreHabitants = nbre;
            this.setCategorie();
          }  


        //*******************************

          //Définit la catégorie de la ville
          private void setCategorie() {

            int bornesSuperieures[] = {0, 1000, 10000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000};
            char categories[] = {'?', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};

            int i = 0;
            while (i < bornesSuperieures.length && this.nbreHabitants > bornesSuperieures[i])
              i++;

            this.categorie = categories[i];
          }

          //Retourne la description de la ville
          public String decrisToi(){
            return "\t"+this.nomVille+" est une ville de "+this.nomPays+ ", elle comporte : "
                    +this.nbreHabitants+" habitant(s) => elle est donc de catégorie : "+this.categorie;
          }

          //Retourne une chaîne de caractères selon le résultat de la comparaison
          public String comparer(Ville v1){
            String str = new String();

            if (v1.getNombreHabitants() > this.nbreHabitants)
              str = v1.getNom()+" est une ville plus peuplée que "+this.nomVille;

            else
              str = this.nomVille+" est une ville plus peuplée que "+v1.getNom();
            return str;  


}
}
```

And

```
        Ville v = new Ville();
        Ville v1 = new Ville("Marseille", 123456, "France");       
        Ville v2 = new Ville("Rio", 321654, "Brésil");



            System.out.println("\n\n"+v1.decrisToi());
            System.out.println(v.decrisToi());
            System.out.println(v2.decrisToi()+"\n\n");
            System.out.println(v1.comparer(v2));
```

Do you know why , the categorie do not appear at the result ?

```
Création d'une ville !
Création d'une ville avec des paramètres !
Création d'une ville avec des paramètres !


    Marseille est une ville de France, elle comporte : 123456 habitant(s) => elle est donc de catégorie :
```

Comment: please write in English and not in French. see [French Language beta](https://french.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Okay, I have read your question and I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, or what the problem is.

Comment: Also press CTRL+SHIFT+F in your editor. You can thank me later.

Comment: I will try to repost in English!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are never calling `setCategorie()`.

Try adjusting your constructor to:

```
    public Ville(String pNom, int pNbre, String pPays) {

        System.out.println("Création d'une ville avec des paramètres !");
        nomVille = pNom;
        nomPays = pPays;
        nbreHabitants = pNbre;
        // Add this !!!
        setCategorie();

        nbreInstances++;
        nbreInstancesBis++;
    }
```

Although a better solution would be to not have a `categorie` instance variable as it solely depends on `nbreHabitants` so you could better do it as:

```
    //Retourne la catégorie de la ville
    public char getCategorie() {

        int bornesSuperieures[] = {0, 1000, 10000, 100000, 500000, 1000000, 5000000, 10000000};
        char categories[] = {'?', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'};

        int i = 0;
        while (i < bornesSuperieures.length && this.nbreHabitants > bornesSuperieures[i])
            i++;

         return categories[i];
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!!  I see I am very thankful to you! thank you and sorry for the French!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue lies in that you never call *setCategorie()* so the *categorie* char is never initialised. You could call this in the constructor for the method to ensure that *categorie* has a value when you call *decrisToi()*.

You'll also have to change the while loop in the method *setCategorie()* as below to ensure that when *nbreHabitants* is 0 *categorie* still gets initialised. Make sure you increment *i* **after** setting *categorie*.

```
    while (i < bornesSuperieures.length && this.nbreHabitants >= bornesSuperieures[i])
```

As a future tip, try and use a standard format for your code so it is easier to read! Most IDEs can do this for you very easily.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do better for the next time!  very sorry for the French,   I will try writing in English the next time,  i am encounting a problem.